# how do i jump down in page by using php after form submits

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a page called buyback.php. in that page there is a form and in the action of the form i said `action="buyback.php"` because i need the page to call itself after the form submits. the form is at the bottom of the page. in that form there is a div that has id result. how do i make the page jump down to that div after the page reloads?

i know that i can use ajax to send the email after the form is submitted and that will not refresh the page after the form submits but i dont know ajax. i am sending the email by using php by saying:-

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
    $result = "Thank you for contacting us. We will reply you as soon as possible";
} else {
    $result = "Message Sending Failed, try again";
}
```

and the div is:-

```
<div id="result"><?php if(isset($result)){ echo $result; } ?></div>
```

i know that i can scroll down to that div if i say `action="buyback.php#result"` but the problem is that if the page is refreshed manually after it scrolls down then it will again scroll down because of the #result in the page url and not all people will figure out that they need to delete the #result

i want to try using `document.getElementById("result").scrollIntoView();` in php to make the page jump down. i tried saying:-

```
echo "<script>";
echo "document.getElementById(\"result\").scrollIntoView();";
echo "</script>";
```

at the end of the php block but that didnt work and all it did was add that javacript line to the top of the page and it didnt scroll down. what do i do to make it work? also can i scroll down in another way?

Comment: Use the `action="buyback.php#result"`  and remove it from the url after the page loaded? Since scrollIntoView() will have to make a check as well to see if it has to scroll or not. Hence i would prefer using the anchor, since that's what anchors are supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Get the result div and check also if have text innered (if this div have text innered post has been submit)

```
var result = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML
```

With this line we get the HTML inner the result div.

Then check if result have length. (If lenght is 0, we don't have message)

```
if(result.length > 0){
    document.getElementById("result").scrollIntoView()
}
```

Comment: i need to know exactly what to say to wrap the javascript that will make the page jump down in php

Comment: You print result `<div id="result"><?php if(isset($result)){ echo $result; } ?></div>` if send message no?

Comment: Edited, maybe you can understand better now

Comment: that is printed at the bottom of the page. i need to jump down to that message after the page reloads

Comment: plz tell me how to write your script inside php. i just echo each line?

Comment: You can put this in footer of your view page with tag `<script></script>`

Answer (score 0):

## Why not using AJAX?

Besides you wont need to return anything else from PHP than the success or error messages, it makes your page a lot more dynamic. This is an example of a working form submission to send a mail with PHP.

#### index.html

```
<form name="sendMail" method="POST" onsubmit="return sendMail()">
   <label for="yourName">Name: </label><input name="yourName">
   <label for="yourEmail">E-Mail: </label><input name="yourEmail">
</form>
```

#### javascriptApp.js

```
function sendMail(){
   let data = {
      name: document.sendMail.yourName.value;
      email: document.sendMail.yourEmail.value;
   };
   const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
   const url='path/to/your/phpfile.php';
   Http.open("POST", url);
   Http.send(data);
   Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
      //Form send with AJAX, now scroll down.
      if( e.responseText == "error" ){
         alert("There was an error sending your data. Try again.");
      }else{
         document.getElementById("result").scrollIntoView();
      }
   }
return false;
}
```

#### mail.php

You just generate your mail content with PHP and send it normally.

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
    echo "done";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Also, I'd recommend you using jQuery, it makes AJAX request with less code, take a look at:

https://jquery.com/

Comment: i want to try it by ajax. can u plz reply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55169328/how-do-i-send-an-email-when-the-form-is-submitted-by-using-ajax