# how do i send an email when the form is submitted by using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have a form on a page called buyback.php and that form is at the bottom of the page. the coding of the form is:-

```
<div class="mktoForm" id="elqForm">
        <form id="elqForm" method="post" name="elqForm" action="buyback.php">
            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718959"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Contact_First_Name"><strong>First Name</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" id="Contact_First_Name" name="Contact_First_Name" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718960"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Contact_Last_Name"><strong>Last Name</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" id="Contact_Last_Name" name="Contact_Last_Name" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718961"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Contact_Email"><strong>Business Email</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" pattern="[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$" id="Contact_Email" name="Contact_Email" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718962"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Job_Responsibility"><strong>Job Title</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" id="Job_Responsibility" name="Job_Responsibility" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718963"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Company_Name"><strong>Company Name</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" id="Company_Name" name="Company_Name" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718964"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Company_Country"><strong>Country</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" id="Company_Country" name="Company_Country" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718965"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Company_State_Province"><strong>City</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" id="Company_State_Province" name="Company_State_Province" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718966"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Contact_Phone_Number"><strong>Business Phone Number</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" id="Contact_Phone_Number" name="Contact_Phone_Number" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718966"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Number_Of_Employees"><strong>Number of Employees</strong> *:</label>
                <select id="Number_Of_Employees" name="Number_Of_Employees">
                    <option value="bet10and49">Between 10 and 49</option>
                    <option value="bet50and99">Between 50 and 99</option>
                    <option value="bet100and199">Between 100 and 199</option>
                    <option value="ab200">Above 200</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow text-center">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718967"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <div class="elqFormRow text-center">
                    <input type="submit" id="elqFormSubmitBut" name="elqFormSubmitBut" class="orange_btn" value="Submit" checkrequired="true">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="result"><?php if(isset($result)){ echo $result; } ?></div>
    </div>
```

in that form there is a div which is `<div id="result"></div>`and i want to print a success message in that form. currently i am reading the field values and sending the email by php by saying:-

```
if ($_POST['elqFormSubmitBut']) {
$Contact_First_Name = $_POST['Contact_First_Name'];
$Contact_Last_Name = $_POST['Contact_Last_Name'];
$Contact_Email = $_POST['Contact_Email'];
$Job_Responsibility = $_POST['Job_Responsibility'];
$Company_Name = $_POST['Company_Name'];
$Company_Country = $_POST['Company_Country'];
$Company_State_Province = $_POST['Company_State_Province'];
$Contact_Phone_Number = $_POST['Contact_Phone_Number'];
$Number_Of_Employees = $_POST['Number_Of_Employees'];

$to = "aaa@gmail.com";
$from = "bbb@gmail.com";

switch ($Number_Of_Employees) {
    case "bet10and49": $Number_Of_Employees = "Between 10 and 49"; break;
    case "bet50and99": $Number_Of_Employees = "Between 50 and 99"; break;
    case "bet100and199": $Number_Of_Employees = "Between 100 and 199"; break;
    case "ab200": $Number_Of_Employees = "Above 200"; break;
}

$message = "
  Contact First Name: $Contact_First_Name<br/>
  Contact Last Name: $Contact_Last_Name<br/>
  Contact Email: $Contact_Email<br/>
  Job Responsibility: $Job_Responsibility<br/>
  Company Name: $Company_Name<br/>
  City: $Company_State_Province<br/>
  Business Phone Number: $Contact_Phone_Number<br/>
  Number Of Employees: $Number_Of_Employees";

$subject = "New Message from the Buyback Form";
$header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'From:'. $from  . " \r\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
    $result = "Thank you for contacting us. We will reply you as soon as possible";
} else {
    $result = "Message Sending Failed, try again";
}
```

}

and i am echoing $result in the div. how do i write the equivalent ajax code to send the email and write the result message in that div? i need someone to plz tell me exactly what to write

Comment: check this sample on  [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38172523/1117368)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, vanilla JavaScript or jQuery.

#### HTML

You don't need any major changes to your HTML, you just need to add a `onsubmit="return function()"` attribute with the function you want to call, in this case we will be using `sendForm()`.

```
<form id="elqForm" method="post" name="elqForm" onsubmit="return sendForm()">
```

#### JavaScript

Somewhere else in your JavaScript code, you must add this lines:

**Vanilla JavaScript:**

```
function sendForm(){
   var form = document.querySelector('elqForm');
   var data = new FormData(form);
   const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
   const url='path/to/your/phpfile.php';
   Http.open("POST", url);
   Http.send(data);
   Http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(Http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && Http.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Http.responseText;
    }
};
return false;
}
```

**With jQuery:**

https://api.jquery.com/

```
function sendForm(){
   var data = $("#elqForm").serialize();
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "path/to/your/phpfile.php",
     data: data,
     success: function(response){
        $("#result").html(response);
     }
   });
}
```

#### PHP

Just change this lines to echo the text you want to output in your div.

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
    echo "Thank you for contacting us. We will reply you as soon as possible";
} else {
    echo "Message Sending Failed, try again";
}
```

Comment: thanks. i am trying to use the jquery way. it said "let definitions are not supported by current javascript version". as for the javascript way it said "expression expected" for Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{. what do i do?

Comment: Use var instead of let. I will edit the answer with both corrections.

Comment: i tried the juery way and i said <div id="result"></div>. when the form is submitted i want to call the same page that has the form. it wrote "Thank you for contacting us. We will reply you as soon as possible" at the top of the page and not in that div and also the page stayed at the top. i need the message to show in that div and i want the page position to stay where it is when the form is submitted and not go to the top

Comment: Are your styles for the div correct for the place where you want it? Also, use $("#result").html(result); instead I edited once more.

Comment: it's still not working :( may i plz have your email address so i can send u my files

Comment: Sure, its in my profile. Im sending it by chat too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190043/discussion-between-k3lly-dev-and-shiddo).

Answer (score 0):

This code has been tested by me

Alot of modifications has been done to your code. More features added like when a message is successful or failed the respectives
messages will fading out after some time via ajax.

okay here is what I have done.
I am sending your data using ajax as you wanted via formData() method.

Your submit button is now modified below.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="orange_btn" name="elqFormSubmitBut"/>
```

Your ajax result div modified below thus removing php script on it

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

At your Server backend your result response has also be modified as per below

```
echo "<div  id='fadebox'>Thank you for contacting us. We will reply you as soon as possible</div>";
```

You can see id having **fadebox** attributes. Thats what fades out result response via ajax post after sometime. You can increase
or reduce the time in the ajax code.

I guess You will need to be online to test your script properly because of the mail

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP AJAX Image Upload</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#elqForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "buyback.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {
            $("#result").html(data);

                                    $('#fadebox').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
            },
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
       });
    }));
});
</script>
</head>
<body>






<div class="mktoForm">
<form id="elqForm" action="buyback.php" method="post">
            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718959"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Contact_First_Name"><strong>First Name</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" id="Contact_First_Name" name="Contact_First_Name" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718960"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Contact_Last_Name"><strong>Last Name</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" id="Contact_Last_Name" name="Contact_Last_Name" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718961"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Contact_Email"><strong>Business Email</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" pattern="[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$" id="Contact_Email" name="Contact_Email" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718962"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Job_Responsibility"><strong>Job Title</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" id="Job_Responsibility" name="Job_Responsibility" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718963"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Company_Name"><strong>Company Name</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" id="Company_Name" name="Company_Name" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718964"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Company_Country"><strong>Country</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" id="Company_Country" name="Company_Country" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718965"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Company_State_Province"><strong>City</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" id="Company_State_Province" name="Company_State_Province" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718966"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Contact_Phone_Number"><strong>Business Phone Number</strong> *:</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" id="Contact_Phone_Number" name="Contact_Phone_Number" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718966"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <label for="Number_Of_Employees"><strong>Number of Employees</strong> *:</label>
                <select id="Number_Of_Employees" name="Number_Of_Employees">
                    <option value="bet10and49">Between 10 and 49</option>
                    <option value="bet50and99">Between 50 and 99</option>
                    <option value="bet100and199">Between 100 and 199</option>
                    <option value="ab200">Above 200</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="elqFormRow text-center">
                <div style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;padding:0;margin:0;max-height:0px;"><a name="eiel1718967"><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="0" style="display:block; height:0px !important;" class="anchorlink_image" alt=""></a></div>
                <div class="elqFormRow text-center">

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="orange_btn" name="elqFormSubmitBut"/>
                      </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

here is the modified **buyback.php**. you can also see how the result response is modified and I just does validate using first_name

```
<?php
// validate  using first name

if ($_POST['Contact_First_Name']) {
$Contact_First_Name = $_POST['Contact_First_Name'];
$Contact_Last_Name = $_POST['Contact_Last_Name'];
$Contact_Email = $_POST['Contact_Email'];
$Job_Responsibility = $_POST['Job_Responsibility'];
$Company_Name = $_POST['Company_Name'];
$Company_Country = $_POST['Company_Country'];
$Company_State_Province = $_POST['Company_State_Province'];
$Contact_Phone_Number = $_POST['Contact_Phone_Number'];
$Number_Of_Employees = $_POST['Number_Of_Employees'];

$to = "aaa@gmail.com";
$from = "bbb@gmail.com";

switch ($Number_Of_Employees) {
    case "bet10and49": $Number_Of_Employees = "Between 10 and 49"; break;
    case "bet50and99": $Number_Of_Employees = "Between 50 and 99"; break;
    case "bet100and199": $Number_Of_Employees = "Between 100 and 199"; break;
    case "ab200": $Number_Of_Employees = "Above 200"; break;
}

$message = "
  Contact First Name: $Contact_First_Name<br/>
  Contact Last Name: $Contact_Last_Name<br/>
  Contact Email: $Contact_Email<br/>
  Job Responsibility: $Job_Responsibility<br/>
  Company Name: $Company_Name<br/>
  City: $Company_State_Province<br/>
  Business Phone Number: $Contact_Phone_Number<br/>
  Number Of Employees: $Number_Of_Employees";

$subject = "New Message from the Buyback Form";
$header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'From:'. $from  . " \r\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
    $result = "";
echo "<div  id='fadebox'>Thank you for contacting us. We will reply you as soon as possible</div>";

} else {

echo "<div  id='fadebox'>Message Sending Failed, try again</div>";
}
}
?>
```